# How to check if numpy array contains empty list

Tags: python, numpy

Here is a sample code for data

```
import numpy as np
myList1 = np.array([1,1,1,[1],1,1,[1],1,1])
myList2 = np.array([1,1,1,[],1,1,[],1,1])
```

To see if elements in myList1 equals to [1] I could do this:

```
myList1 == [1]
```

But for myList2, to see if elements in myList2 equals to [] I COULDN'T do this:

```
myList2 == []
```

I had to do:

```
[x == [] for x in myList2]
```

Is there another way to look for elements in lists that will also handle empty lists? some other function in numpy or python that I could use?

Comment: That doesn't even run without specifying `dtype`.

Comment: what doesn't run?

Comment: np.array([1,1,1,[1],1,1,[1],1,1]) gives an error ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: that's weird,  works on my machine.

Comment: It's a `numpy` thing; it works for me after updating to 1.16.

Comment: I want to avoid using list comprehension, and find a solution that is going to be universal for any data. Because it feels like something so simple yet has to do something somewhat complicated doesn't feel right for python. haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array with a mix of numbers and lists (empty or not) is `object dtype`. This is practically a `list`; fast compiled `numpy` math no longer works. The only practical alternative to a list comprehension is `np.frompyfunc`.

Write a small function that can distinguish between a number and list and length of list, and apply that to the array. If it returns True for an empty list, then `np.where` will identify the location

```
In [41]: myList1 = np.array([1,1,1,[1],1,1,[1],1,1]) 
    ...: myList2 = np.array([1,1,1,[],1,1,[],1,1])
```

Develop a function that returns True for a empty list, False otherwise:

```
In [42]: len(1)                                                                 
...
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
In [43]: len([])                                                                
Out[43]: 0

In [44]: def foo(item): 
    ...:     try: 
    ...:         return len(item)==0 
    ...:     except TypeError: 
    ...:         pass 
    ...:     return False 
    ...:                                                                        
In [45]: foo([])                                                                
Out[45]: True
In [46]: foo([1])                                                               
Out[46]: False
In [47]: foo(1)                                                                 
Out[47]: False
```

Apply it to the arrays:

```
In [48]: f=np.frompyfunc(foo,1,1)                                               
In [49]: f(myList1)                                                             
Out[49]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
      dtype=object)
In [50]: np.where(f(myList1))                                                   
Out[50]: (array([], dtype=int64),)
In [51]: np.where(f(myList2))                                                   
Out[51]: (array([3, 6]),)
```